# LINQ не переводит FirstOrDefault() на язык SQL. Работает, если там поставить Count()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
{

    outputForm myForm = new outputForm();

    var list = db.Penalties.GroupBy(key => key.IdDriversNavigation.FullName,
                                       record => record.IdTraficCopNavigation.FullName,
                                       (key, record) => new
                                       {
                                           driver = key,
                                           traficCop = record.FirstOrDefault()
                                       });

    myForm.myGrid.DataSource = list.ToList();

    myForm.Show();
}
```

************** Текст исключения **************

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: (d.FullName), 
ElementSelector:(ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
)
    .FirstOrDefault()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю в этом месте нет ещё никакой последовательности, она будет на следующем шаге, ну то есть кажется надо сделать следом .Select и там уже отбирать всякое нужное.

Comment: Пожалуйста, отформатируйте код, невозможно прочесть с мобильного.

Comment: Какой запрос ты ожидал получить и какой получил? Почему ты думаешь, что не переводит?

Comment: Не переводит потому, что об этом говорится в исключении, которое получается при данном вызове. Я ожидаю получить таблицу в две колонки, где в одной строке в первой колонке будет запись driver(одна запись), а во  второй первая запись(FirstOrDefault()) из коллекции traficCop(запрос возвращает коллекцию). Код будет работать, если вместо первой(FirstOrDefault()) записи возвращать количество(Count), остальные методы(Any(), Last()) также вызывают исключения

Comment: Добавь текст исключения непосредственно в вопрос

Comment: При редактировании не надо было заменять на Count, так как сейчас никакой ошибки нет.

Comment: [известная проблема](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12088) решений пока не предвидится.

Comment: @Grundy Я понял. Жаль, конечно. Спасибо за помощь!